# How could I use JS to transform given array to other arrays?

Tags: javascript

I need a function and the requirement like this:

- Given dimensions of the array, return all the combination arrays of
  the given number.
- The length of given array is the length of the array in return array
- The combination size is the result of the numbers in given array to
  multiply. For example: given [2, 2], size is 2*2=4; given [2, 1, 2],
  size is 2*1*2=4.
- The number in given array (subtract 1) is the max number of that
  column.

I know it's not clear but it seems hard to explain, so look at the examples. Some examples like this:

```
given: [1, 1]
return: [[0, 0]]

given: [2, 2]
return: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]

given: [2, 3]
return: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]

given: [3, 3]
return: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]

given: [1, 1, 1]
return: [[0, 0, 0]]

given: [1, 1, 2]
return: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]

given: [2, 1, 2]
return: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]

given: [2, 2, 2]
return: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]

......
```

How can I use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/) or any other libs to write this function? Thanks.

===========**UPDATED**===========

Finally I solved the problem by use the [cartesian product of js-combinatorics](https://github.com/dankogai/js-combinatorics#cartesian-product) and lodash.
First I can easy transform the given array to some arrays:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

const givenArr = [2, 1, 2];
const arr = givenArr.map((v) => _.range(v)); 
console.log(arr); // [[0, 1], [0], [0, 1]]
```

And pass the transformed array to he js-combinatorics api:

```
const cp = Combinatorics.cartesianProduct([0, 1], [0], [0, 1]);
console.log(cp.toArray()); 
// [ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ], [ 1, 0, 1 ] ]
```

Comment: Currently I don't even get the connection between input and output. Furthermore I can not notice any efforts of yourself to solve the problem at hand ...

Comment: You don't even say what it is you're doing. Your question is like a strange puzzle where you have to figure out the relationship between maths sequences or something.

Comment: What is the logic between the given and the return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after the update I actually understand the problem.

As for the solution. I think a recursive approach would be best here. I'll just give the pseudocode and leave implementation up to you:

```
function getAllCombinations( inputArr ) {

  if inputArr has just one element {
    return a list with all possible values
  }

  first = get the first element of the input array

  newInput = inputArr with the first element removed

  subResult = getAllCombinations( newInput )

  result = empty list

  for each possible value for the first element of the result as newElement 
  (can be enumerated by using first) {
    combine newElement with subResult and put in result
  }

  return result
}
```

So the idea behind is, take the first element out of the input, recursively generate all solutions for the smaller input. Afterwards combine the solutions with all possible elements resulting from the first element.

Base case is, when the input array has just one element. Here the answer is a list of all possible values for that cell.

Comment: Thanks for your pseudocode and patience, I'll try to implement it later.